# if a div height more than 300 addclass otherwise if the height is not more the 300 remove the calss

Tags: jquery, css

I want to add a scroll bar when height is more then 300px but if the height is not more then 300 scroll will be remove.

i [image]

[image]

Comment: Okay. Where is your code and what specific issue are you having?

Comment: it's quite easy... add `max-height: 300px; overflow: auto`

Comment: function checkSize(){
  if($("#sidebar-container").height() == 300) {
    $('.sidebar-arrow-up').addClass('arrow-show');
  }
  else{
    $('.sidebar-arrow-up').removeClass('arrow-show');
  }
}

Comment: what if container is less than 300px? here's a basic jsfiddle based on @KalpeshSingh answer: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/4vxjd9u7/

Comment: It shouldn't. That's what OP asked, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can check this for adding dynamic scrollbar by checking its height:

Check: http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/p3FFL/

```
$(function(){
    alert('content 1: ' + $('#my_div1').hasScrollBar());
    alert('content 2: ' + $('#my_div2').hasScrollBar());
});

(function($) {
    $.fn.hasScrollBar = function() {
        return this.get(0).scrollHeight > this.height();
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also approach it through the CSS.

Here's an example on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/justjoe22/nw7noj4h/5/

HTML:

```
<div id="scroll1">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>I have some text here that is longer than 300px height, but its height is undefined (height can be between 0 and whatever)</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>I have text here less than 300px height</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="scroll2">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>I have some text here that is longer than 300px height, but its height is undefined (height can be between 0 and whatever)</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>I have text here less than 300px height</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#scroll1,
#scroll2 {
  max-height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  max-height: inherit;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

li {
  max-height: inherit;
  overflow: auto;
}

li:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#scroll1 li div {
  height: auto;
}

#scroll1 li div {
  height: 400px;
}
```